# Joining multiple sub folders inside an azure datalake using adf join

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake-gen2

I am trying to join 2 folders inside a gen2 container, using azure data factory join activity. Each folder has multiple sub folders.
The structure of the container is as follows:

```
conianer
   folder1 
      sub folder1/
              file/
      sub folder 2/
              file
   folder2/
      sub folder 1/
            file/
      sub folder 2/
            file/
```

When trying to preview the dataset in adf I get the following error:

> (at Source 'csvparquet': Path abfss://container@storageaccount.dfs.core.windows.net/directory does not resolve to any file(s). Please make sure the file/folder exists and is not hidden. At the same time, please ensure special character is not included in file/folder name, for example, name starting with _)

I renamed all the folders in the datalake removing all special characters, and I still get the same error.
How would I use wildcard path to select all the files inside the sub folder for each folder to be joined together.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the above scenario in my environment, and I got same error in ADF dataflow.

This is my path in the parquet dataset.

[image]

It gave the below error.

[image]

ADF dataflow requires a file name or the last child folder name to get the data preview.

> How would I use wildcard path to select all the files inside the sub folder for each folder to be joined together

Joining is a different concept in ADF dataflow which involves inner join, outer join etc... with [Data flow join transformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-join).

But **if your ask is to merge the files from different sub folders of `folder1`** and wants to get a preview of it, then give the wild card path in the dataflow like below and your file path in the dataset is same as above(`data/folder1/`).

`**/*.parquet`

[image]

If you want to get the files from all folders `foler1`,`folder2`,.. from the container `data`, give the path till the container in the dataset. And in the wild card paths of the dataflow, chane the expression like this `**/**/*.parquet`.

**Data preview:**

[image]

Comment: thank you for your response. I am now able to review the datasets, however I am getting null values in one of the data sources, adf dataflow is unable to read the dataset, I was able to read the same dataset in azure databricks perfectly. What do you think the issue is?

Comment: are your files have same schema? ADF dataflow will give null values for the extra columns if the schema of all files is not same? Can you provide your data preview image, file path in dataset image and wild card path image as well if possible?

Comment: I can't seem to upload image, it's saying i it's loo large to upload.

Comment: data preview: contains 5 columns all null values, however it also contains the 17 columns from the other data source which contains data.

Comment: Try to import projection in the dataflow and check again in the dataflow.

Comment: I did exactly that and I still got the null values. I think I know what the problem was, I thought I had converted the "id" column as an integer using databricks, however when I went back to databricks and printed the schema it did not get converted for some reason. I have just now done the transformation, and saved it onto my data lake. Do you think that was the issue?

Comment: I don't think that will be the issue. After converting back to integer, are you not getting the null values?

Comment: I'm still getting the null values, my files have the same schema. I don't understand what the problem is

Comment: I am able to view the data in azure synapse perfectly

Comment: I was able to preview the dataset with inline source type